# data.table equivalent for: case_when - Invalid regex when using emails on it?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've a list of emails, I want to compare against a DB column, named `correo` (spanish for email).

So, let's say this is the list of emails to use:

```
users_emails <-"18maryalma@gmail.com|2013311097@edu.pe|40491118@cotal.edu.pe|956145120jh@gmail.com|975625735o@gmail.com"
```

When using `case_when` and `grepl` to match them to the data base, I get:

```
Error in grepl(users_emails, correo, ignore.case = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '18maryalma@gmail.com|2013311097@edu.pe...
```

**Code:**

```
db <- db %>%
            mutate(
              secciones = case_when(
                grepl(users_emails, 
                      correo, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ TRUE)
              )
```

**data:**

```
db <- structure(list(idusuario = c(2L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 11L), ecoid = c(47L, 
1878686L, 355078L, 2667803L, 2680290L, 2680842L), facebookid = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), twitterid = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), googleid = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), nombres = c("carlos", "Max", "Estibens Manuel", 
"Hernan", "angie", "Dennys Dante"), apellidos = c("gdrab", "Palomino", 
"' or 1=1", "Galvez", "cotaquispe palomino", "Angeles"), correo = c("cfrasan@gmail.com", 
"maxpalominomendoza@gmail.com", "estibensmanchego@gmail.com", 
"hgb2431@gmail.com", "patito_luz_07@hotmail.com", "dangeles@americatv.com.pe"
), nickname = c("cfrasan666", NA, "estibensmancheg", NA, NA, 
NA), genero = c("M", "M", "M", "M", NA, "M"), avatar = c("http://peruid.e3.pe/ima/0/0/0/0/0/thumb/1338410240_47.jpg", 
"http://peruid.pe/f/i/gadget/avatar-4.jpg", "http://peruid.pe/f/i/gadget/avatar-6.jpg", 
"http://s.elcomercio.pe/uploads/default.jpg", "http://s.elcomercio.pe/uploads/default.jpg", 
"http://s.elcomercio.pe/uploads/default.jpg"), avatar_url = c("http://peruid.e3.pe/ima/0/0/0/0/0/thumb/avatar/1338410240_47.jpg", 
"http://peruid.pe/f/i/gadget/avatar-4.jpg", "http://peruid.pe/f/i/gadget/avatar-6.jpg", 
"http://s.elcomercio.pe/uploads/default.jpg", "http://s.elcomercio.pe/uploads/default.jpg", 
"http://s.elcomercio.pe/uploads/default.jpg"), status = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), fecha = c("1997-03-01", "1986-02-02", "1986-04-22", 
"1984-03-15", "0000-00-00", "1984-05-28"), version = c(34L, 49L, 
99L, 11L, 1L, 2L), pais = c("PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE"
), suscriptor = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L), telefono = c("95286265", 
"965312230", "014274434", "976926796", NA, "981306661"), ciudad = c("Lima y Callao", 
"Lima y Callao", "Lima y Callao", "Lima y Callao", NA, "Lima"
), acceso = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), clave = c("sha256:1024:OT9jxBY0cGm+hC3ZQqx+HqE12uAuaqzG:rYTfX", 
"sha256:1024:ddreAcaw8oRPeoE/s5rO/+eMpypBjYyv:MqAYX", "sha256:1024:GqbedkIqtC/ersJvwCPnn78ztIj0CJMR:jOrp+", 
"sha256:1024:7P6+L6h/nQawwFXs9q/Ri9gDzOOstWKk:JwsVX", "sha256:1024:jdrS3ctfG1aa9sNY4csqo/f306T6yyqy:LQtMu", 
"sha256:1024:lbiQYFd668n2E+5zg5bLk0QpeULUJ+Xn:fUtYv"), nueva_clave_key = c(NA, 
"", "2cc9b4cf343011eb94b3cc685f1c91b87f1974db", "", NA, NA), 
    nueva_clave_requested = c(NA, "2016-01-29 17:45:34", "2015-08-02 18:57:44", 
    "2015-07-08 12:30:17", NA, NA), acepto_politicas = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), fecha_registro = c("0000-00-00 00:00:00", 
    "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", 
    "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:00:00"), fecha_actualizado = structure(c(1485147600, 
    1535950800, 1498280400, 1498798800, 1481346000, 1488517200
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), dni = c("41764577", 
    "41773997", "44548862", "42311024", "", "42381593"), direccion = c("jose mariategui S/n", 
    "Calle rosacruces 270 San Gregorio are vitarte", "Av. Emancipacion 153 int. 304", 
    "Carlos alayza y roel 2331", "", "Av Jose Leguia y Melendez 1837"
    ), apellido_ma = c("rinjo", "Mendoza", "Melendez", "Bellido", 
    "", "Fuentes"), envio = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), envio_fecha = c("0000-00-00 00:00:00", 
    "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", 
    "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:00:00"), paquete_suscriptor = c("0", 
    "1", "0", "1", "0", "0"), paquete_suscriptor_fecha = c("2016-12-23 12:45:18", 
    "2017-02-16 15:10:37", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "2016-10-21 10:08:05", 
    "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:00:00"), departamento = c(15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 0L, 15L), provincia = c(6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L), distrito = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 16L, 0L, 21L), ga_userid_is_in_db = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), secciones = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Still getting errors, it wasn't the emails but also happens when using numbers (as strings).

**Does anyone know how to do this with data.table?**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**:

Should work with number ids also:

```
users_ids <- dput(head(users_ids))
c(996683L, 996177L, 994826L, 991164L, 991L, 990744L)
```

Code:

```
setDT(db)[Reduce(`|`, lapply(users_ids, function(es)
  grepl(es, idusuario, ignore.case = TRUE))), ga_usersids_in_db := TRUE][]
```

Comment: your code worked for me

Comment: I'm not getting the same error, try restarting r or clearing your environment? I did notice none of the user emails were in the correo column, so I substituted the first one of the correo column and the case_when works as expected

Comment: It is working for me

Comment: @akrun I still got this problem. Do you know of a data.table equivalent? I'd like to try it to see if it makes any difference. See update 1, pls-

Comment: @OmarGonzales posted couple of solutions

Comment: @OmarGonzales for your 'users_emails', how many are there in `|`.  there should be a limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fcase` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(db)[, secciones := fcase(grepl(users_emails, correo, ignore.case = TRUE), TRUE)]
```

Or without any `fcase`

```
setDT(db)[grepl(users_emails, correo, ignore.case = TRUE), secciones := TRUE][]
```

---

If there are many emails, it may be better to loop and `Reduce`

```
emails <- strsplit(users_emails, "|", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
setDT(db)[Reduce(`|`, lapply(emails, function(es)
    grepl(es, correo, ignore.case = TRUE))), secciones := TRUE][]
```

Comment: got the same error with data.table. I've 5000 emails, in `users_emails`, could be more. Is this the problem?

Comment: @OmarGonzales try with the last option

Comment: Also, I can't use the fcase solution, as it is not found in my data.table, is it in dev version?

Comment: @OmarGonzales that would be dev version, I think the safest is the last option.  try it

Comment: I got: `grepl(es, idusuario, ignore.case = TRUE))), ga_userid_in_db := TRUE][]
Error: inesperado ')' in "  grepl(es, idusuario, ignore.case = TRUE))"` I've changed some varibales to match my setup.

Comment: @OmarGonzales earlier there was a `)` missing.  Can you check now

Comment: same error, maybe is because I'm not using the emails this time but id numbers, please, see update 2. So I' was ommitting first line of your last solution.

Comment: @OmarGonzales. The first line is just to create a vector as the 'users_emails' were a single string

Comment: @OmarGonzales I am not getting any error ` setDT(db)[Reduce(`|`, lapply(user_ids, function(es)
     grepl(es, correo, ignore.case = TRUE))), secciones := TRUE][]`

Comment: could you try the code I've posted recently in update 2. There is the users_ids and the DT code I'm using. It's getting me the same error.

Comment: @OmarGonzales i tried it, no error `setDT(db)[Reduce(`|`, lapply(users_ids, function(es)
   grepl(es, idusuario, ignore.case = TRUE))), ga_usersids_in_db := TRUE][]`

Comment: @OmarGonzales I am using R 4.0.  Can you change the `lapply(as.character(users_ids), `

Comment: Now is running, 5 min now, but well it's 290 000 obs and 5000 users_ids. I'll keep running test, the other thing that could be happening is that I've acquired "new memory rams" and overcloked them...

Comment: @OmarGonzales if it is a big data and have 5000 user_ids, it wuld take some time or else you can split the user_ids, do this in parallel, and later Reduce